# Final Render, does not show the model?

Tags: rendering, layers

As the title says, here is the blend file, the problem is present both in cycles and blender render.

I can see the model in rendered view, but when I render it, the render shows up blank.

[image: Wut]

Blend File:

https://ufile.io/elf9p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a layers issue. Blender have multiple layers, and also multiple render layers. The render layer determines which layers to render. So if there is no model in Your render layer, the render will come out blank.

You have not selected the render layer which the model is in. In the right side make sure that the same layer is selected as in the bottom of the screen. To learn about layers, [check this out](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/layers.html)

[image]